# Home page redirect to the X Folder - Google make any difference for the home page Ranking?

Tags: seo, search-engine, http-status-code-301

I just find that One of my client website (Home page) redirect to "x" folder.

Like www.example.com ► 301 redirect to  ► www.example.com/x/

Also into Google search result i am finding that most of the keywords come with Home page URL.

Should this redirection make any difference to keyword ranking?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

301 redirection signals to search engines that the resource has moved permanently and signals to attribute the existing SEO values to the new URL. After certain point in time, search engines will index the new URL and drop the old URL as you have signaled that the resource has moved permanently (theoretically).

With this redirection, search engines will start looking at **new URL** and evaluate against ranking algorithm. Search engine crawlers will stop going through the old URL and keywords/content of old pages does not make sense anymore.